# Member of a class isn't changed on assignment

Tags: delphi

I have the following setup:

```
//code from unit
...
TObjectList<T:TObject>=class(TObject)
private
  function GetItem(Name: string): T;
  function GetItemByIndex(Index: Integer): T;
public
  property Items[Name:string]:T read GetItem;default;
  property Item[Index:Integer]:T read GetItemByIndex;
end;

...
{ TObjectList<T> }

function TObjectList<T>.GetItem(Name: string): T;
begin
Result:=T(FindComponent(Name));
end;

function TObjectList<T>.GetItemByIndex(Index: Integer): T;
begin
Result:=T(Components[Index]);
end;
...
TStringEval=record
private
  FValue:string;
public
  function AsString:string;
  function AsInteger:Integer;
  function AsFloat:Double;
  function AsBoolean:Boolean;
  function AsDateTime:TDateTime;
  function AsHex:string;
  procedure SetValue(const S:string);overload;
  procedure SetValue(const I:Integer;const AsHex:boolean=false);overload;
  procedure SetValue(const F:Double);overload;
  procedure SetValue(const B:Boolean);overload;
  procedure SetValue(const D:TDateTime);overload;
...
TConsoleVariable=class(TConsoleCommand)
...
  property Value:TStringEval read GetValue write SetValue;
...
TConsole=class(TObjectList<TConsoleCommand>)
...
  property Variables[Name:string]:TConsoleVariable read GetVariable;
...

function TConsole.GetVariable(Name: string): TConsoleVariable;
begin
Result:=TConsoleVariable(Items[Name]);
end;
...
//main application code, the troublesome line.
Console.Variables['developer'].Value.SetValue(MESSAGELEVEL_VERBOSE);
...
```

This line never changes the value of the variable for reasons I can't understand. There are also similar problems with other parts of my code. The console variable is initially assigned the value of 1, by the console itself. I wanted temporarily to set it higher to get more verbose output from the application without recompiling the code of console (it's in a package).

Comment: Hard to review an incomplete code that can't be compiled; probably your code assigns a value to a hidden temporary variable instead of a variable you need.

Comment: For the record, the code is placed in several units, spread across the application and package, how do you expect me to show it so you could compile it?

Comment: Make a SSCCE reproducing the problem; not a hard thing to do for sure.

Comment: @ZzZombo I know doing that takes time but the net result is a better question. You also make it easier for you to see and explore the problem and that's always good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you are not changing the stored value, rather you change a copy of it.

```
Console.Variables['developer'].Value.SetValue(MESSAGELEVEL_VERBOSE);
```

This is the code that attempts to make a modification. The `TStringEval` instance is yielded by the `Value` property:

```
property Value: TStringEval read GetValue write SetValue;
```

You did not show the getter for the property but it must return a copy because `TStringEval` is a record, a value type.

One way to resolve the issue would be to make `TStringEval` be a reference type. That is to convert it from a record to a class. That's quite a drastic change which you might not care to take on.

Another option would be to assign to `Value` rather than call methods on it:

```
Console.Variables['developer'].Value := NewValue;
```

And this leads onto what I would regard as the fundamental design flaw in your code. You have a value type that has methods that mutate `Self`. This is a design mistake that has been made so many times by so many different programmers. In recent times some of the most spectacular instances have been found in the FireMonkey library which commits this error repeatedly.

The reason why having methods of value types that mutate the value is exemplified by the issue in your question. If you did not have mutating methods of your value type, then you could not fall into this trap. So, I suggest that you remove all the `SetValue` methods and replace them with static class functions that return new values:

```
class function New(const S: string): TStringEval; static; overload;
```

Then the only way to modify the value is like this:

```
Console.Variables['developer'].Value := TStringEval.New(...);
```

Indeed you could even use an implicit cast operator to make the syntax even more spare.

Comment: Eh, I even thought about your solution (to create a static method returning new records), but discarded it. I'll try it now. Thanks. I suspected that you have explained, but wasn't sure back then. Now it all makes sense.